# 16.04 scale for menu erratic behavior

Tags: unity, 16.04, hdpi

I have recently upgraded my Ubuntu to 16.04
Having a high resolution screen, I tried to use the "scale for menus and title bars" options in Settings > Displays.

But this is giving me strange results:

At 1,88 icons on the launchpad are fine, but the one on the desktop are still very small. Titles are too big.

[image]

At 2, there is this huge jump in behavior where things become huge. Some desktop icons are big, other stay small.

[image]

What is going on ?